I am trying to host a next.js application through vercel and keep running into an error where it says it can't find the images im using
I built a next.js portfolio app. Everything works fine when i run it through npm but when i try to host on vercel (and even on render) it pops up with the following error:

Here is the github code.
I expected it to deploy with little problems.

Looking at your code in github, it appears that your image files in question are named with a capitalized .PNG instead of .png. Rename them to lower case, and you should be fine.


so I tried it both ways and it wouldn't work. So I got a wild hair earlier and just converted the pics to jpg and now it hosts just fine. Thank you for your time.
